# Set UITextField text property in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, segue

I have a textField in my ViewController1. I have a push segue to my ViewController2 which also has a textField. I need to set the textField.text in my ViewController2 to be equal to the text in the textField in my ViewController1. Here's the code I have:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"ViewController2"])
    {
        ViewController2 *VCT = [segue destinationViewController];
        VCT.title = @"View Controller #2";
        VCT.textField.text = self.textField.text;
    }
}
```

The title setter works just fine. Why is the textField not working?

Comment: NSLog self.textField.text

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot set the text of the `UITextField` (and any other components like `UILabel` and `UITextView`) in the prepare for segue, because all view components of the recently allocated controller are not initialized yet (at this time, they are all `nil`), they only will be when the viewController is presented (and it's view loaded).

You have to create a `NSString` property in the presented viewController, and then, somewhere inside your another view controller, like `viewDidLoad`, set the text of the textField as this property value.

Like this:

In the viewController that will present the another viewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ViewController2"])
    {
        ViewController2 *vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc2.myString = self.textField.text;
    }
}
```

And inside the presented viewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    (...)
    self.textField.text = self.myString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if "`VCT.textField`" is not nil at that point.  I suspect that you'll find it is nil.

You either need to expose it via "`@property (strong) IBOutlet UITextField * textField`" or you need to store the string somewhere else (e.g. a "`NSString`" property?) which then loads the text field when the view is fully loaded.