# Passing data between view controllers produces nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I'm a new programmer and struggling with passing data between controllers, I am aware this question is asked in these forums but the uploaded code is much more complex compared to mine and i struggle to understand it so will upload my few lines i've written.  I want to allow two players to type their names into my app and then click start game. when the start game button is pressed it takes them to a new view controller which has their names like this Joe Bloggs vs John Doe, I can achieve this IF i make my variables global but my understanding is this is bad practice so when i try and write the same code keeping the variables inside the View Controller it passes nil each time and i'm unsure what i have done wrong? Here is my few lines of code that i hope someone can answer what i'm doing wrong?

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerOneName: String!
    var playerTwoName: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var playerOneTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerTwoTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func startGameButton(_ sender: Any) {

        playerOneName = playerOneTextField.text!
        playerTwoName = playerTwoTextField.text!

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue" {

            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! GameViewController
            destinationVC.playerOne.text = playerOneName
            destinationVC.playerTwo.text = playerTwoName
        }
    }

}
```

GameViewController:

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerTwo: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the text fields are correctly mapped to the variables? What if `prepare(for:sender:)` is called before the button callback?

Comment: Because `playerOne` is `nil` when you do `destinationVC.playerOne.text = playerOneName`. In other words, the `IBOulet` is not loaded yet. Create a `String` property which will hold the `playerOneName` value. On the `viewDidLoad()` set the `playerOne.text` to it.

Comment: In Objective-C, but reason is the same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137073/set-uitextfield-text-property-in-prepareforsegue or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576177/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-uilabel-following-a-segue

Answer (score 2):

You can't set properties of `@IBOutlets` before you controller is initialized.
You need to store values like `String!` in second view controller. And init `@IBOutlets` with them in `viewDidLoad` method for example.

Change `GameViewController` code to this:

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var playerOne: UILabel!
    var playerOneName: String!     

    @IBOutlet weak var playerTwo: UILabel!
    var playerTwoName: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playerOne.text = playerOneName
        playerTwo.text = playerTextName
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

And `prepare` in `ViewController`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! GameViewController
        destinationVC.playerOneName = playerOneName
        destinationVC.playerTwoName = playerTwoName
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set the label's text directly from another view controller, but create variables in `GameViewController` to store the label text, change those variables in the segue and then change the label in your destination controller's `viewDidLoad` method. See below code.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerTwo: UILabel!

    var playerOneName:String?
    var playerTwoName:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playerOne.text = playerOneName
        playerTwo.text = playerTwoName
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

}
```

And in ViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue" {

            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! GameViewController
            destinationVC.playerOneName = playerOneName
            destinationVC.playerTwoName = playerTwoName
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outlets don't get initialized until your controller's view is loaded.  However, the segue happens before that.

The best solution is to put a couple of string properties into `GameViewController` and use those to receive the data from your first controller.  Then, update your label text in `viewDidLoad`.