# Swift: Issues passing data between tableview cell to a secondary viewcontroller with a UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

Using Xcode and Swift, I have created a tableview, where I have 11 different cells within it. Each cell are custom made and only contains an image. My goal is that when I press one of the cells, it will transition onto a secondary viewcontroller. The image that the chosen cell contains will then be passed onto the secondary viewcontroller and can be seen within an imageview in the secondary view controller.

This is the code for my primary viewcontroller where I have my tableview:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
    
        let vc = showViewViewController(nibName: "showViewViewController", bundle: nil)
        vc.paintingImage?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Picture5")
        
        let showPainting = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "showView")
        view.window?.rootViewController = showPainting
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    
    }
```

And this is the only code I have for my secondary viewcontroller. Within the storyboard of my secondary viewcontroller i only have that one imageView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var paintingImage: UIImageView!
```

When i run the application I get no error, but the imageview just remains blanc, as if it can't reach the image for some reason. Hope this helps.

Comment: What are you expecting to do with `vc`? You seem to be instantiating two controllers `vc` and `showPainting` where you set an image on the first (assuming the view is loaded at the time), yet you present the second.

Comment: Just updated post, but ShowPainting is the transition to reach the secondary viewcontroller, whereas vc was supposed reach the imageview in the secondary viewcontroller and change the image.

Comment: `paintingImage` should be nil. Because you did instantiate the viewController, but it didn't load all its views. Either you force a `loadView()`, or you do (preferred action), set a `UIImage` property, and you'll do `vc.thatImageProperty = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Picture5")`, and in `viewDidLoad()`, `paintingImage.image = thatImageProperty`

Comment: Forcing a loadView() isn't working for me unfortunately, and i'm not quite sure what you mean by the other solution sorry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676205/passing-data-between-view-controllers-produces-nil etc.

Comment: Makes sense, and also tried it out, but it still seems empty, but know i feel like it's a different error. Just tried to put a image inside the imageView and the viewcontroller was still blanc, like I somehow is showing an empty screen, even if i put a label within the secondary viewcontroller.